# Stuck on Joker and EDI in the cockpit? (Probable bug)

Tags: mass-effect-3

Twice now I've gotten stuck in place after running into the cockpit to say hi to EDI and Joker. I can interact with them, which is nice, but I can't move, not even to just turn in place. Reloading solves the problem, but I was wondering if anyone else was running into this annoying little problem.

Comment: You're not the only one.

Comment: In the PC version, i have managed to escape by button-mashing the movement controls randomly for about five seconds. Don't know if it works on consoles.